# Не понимаю, как работает добавление элемента в конец связного списка java

Tags: java, linked-list

Допустим, вот код связного списка, простые три операции: добавление в начало списка, в конец, и вывод списка. Единственный момент, который я не понимаю, это как работает добавление в конец списка. В "начало" всё просто, мы создаем новый узел, присваиваем ему значение старый ссылки, в свою очередь "началу" или "голове" присваиваем значение нового узла. А вот, как работает эти строки: **tail.next = newNode;  tail = newNode;** для меня загадка. Ведь здесь не создаются новые экземпляры (tail это единственный экземпляр класса MyLinkedList), при этом при добавление нового элемента, ссылки на предыдущие элементы почему то не теряются. Прошу объяснить доступным для такого не далекого человека языком, именно этот момент.

```
public class MyLinkedList {
    Node head;
    Node tail;

 

    void addToHead(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);

        if (head == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
           newNode.next = head;
           head = newNode;
        }

    }

    void addToTail(int data) {
        Node newNode = new Node(data);

        if (tail == null) {
            head = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        } else {
            tail.next = newNode;
            tail = newNode;
        }
    }

    void printAll() {
        Node node = head;
        while (node != null) {
            System.out.print(node.data + " ");
            node = node.next;
        }
    }

    static class Node {
        Node next;
        int data;
        

        Node(int data) {
            this.data = data;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return Node.class.getName() + " data: " + data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да ведь это **ничем** не отличается от вставки в начало. Что же вас смущает?

Comment: Тем, что когда мы добавляем в начало мы каждый раз используем новый экземпляр newNode.next, и понятно что на что ссылается. А когда в конец, мы используем единственный экземпляр tail, который заново не создается, и при этом мы каждый раз присваиваем tail новую ссылку, на новый node, но предыдущие ссылки почему то сохраняются, не могу понять почему

Comment: А вот это что в начале addToTail?   `Node newNode = new Node(data);`

Comment: Чтобы объяснить мне, вы должны понять, почему я не понимаю, а не сделать, чтобы я не понимал ещё больше xD Node newNode = new Node(data) - это мы создаем новый экземпляр класса Node. Но ведь я не об этом спрашиваю, я вроде довольно конкретно описал, что я не понимаю. Скорей всего у меня просто пробелы в знаниях о том, как объекты ссылаются друг на друга. В моем понимание это так: obj1 = obj2 (предыдущая ссылка на obj1 стёрлась, теперь и obj1 и obj2 ссылаются на одно и тоже). Вот и с такой концепцией я не понимаю, почему при добавление нового элемента в список, не стирается пред. ссылка tail

Comment: Текст вопроса: _tail это единственный экземпляр класса MyLinkedList_  Код в вопросе: `Node tail;`

Comment: @NowhereMan вы сюда поумничать заходите или помочь? Да ошибся, но вы же поняли, что я имел в ввиду. Не понимаю таких людей

Comment: @DimaIsaev, неправильная реакция.  Правильная реакция: исправить _свою_ ошибку, отредактировав вопрос.  По поводу помощи - MBo уже всё объяснил достаточно качественно, так что можете поблагодарить его, приняв его ответ -- для этого надо поставить зелёную галочку.  Удачи!

Answer (score 3):

Было

```
 a  ->  b  ->  с ->  NULL
 ^             ^ 
 |             |   
head           tail
```

`tail` является синонимом узла `c`

Добавляем в конец.  `tail` пока равен `c`, поэтому `tail.next = newNode;` то же самое, что `с.next = newNode;`

```
 a  ->  b  ->  с ->  d  -> null
 ^             ^ 
 |             |   
head           tail
```

Делаем `tail` синонимом узла `d`  (`tail = newNode;`)

```
 a  ->  b  ->  с ->  d  -> null
 ^                   ^ 
 |                   |   
head                tail
```